# Send button halts until file is uploded to the server?

Tags: android

I am uploding files from my phone to the server when i click on the send button the activity hangs up until the complete file gets uploaded on the server..how to remove this behavior..should i use a broadcast for this or something else..Plz suggest.

the code for sending the file is inside the on click method of the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html describes how to property do long-running operations in Android without hanging up UI

Comment: @Harinder you can pass `String[]` or `List<String>` to `AsyncTask`